# How To store data in ethereum network using truffle framework ?How to achieve the database layer in dapps?

Tags: solidity, truffle, dapps, storage

I am creating a dapp which has to be a login authentication system and some datas has to be store in database.  So I really cant' store all the datas in Solidity's variable or class object, it has to be a backend connection setup with the dataase like sql or nosql. If I am using some kind of database like mysql or mongodb etc..then doesn't this neglect the point of decentralised apps? If so, what's the solution?  Any example or article would help good. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try out a project like [BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com/) or [Filecoin](https://filecoin.io/)

For decentralized authentication take a look at [uPort](https://www.uport.me) and [Blockstack](https://blockstack.org), Blockstack also includes decentralized storage (Gaia)

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a dapp which has to be a login authentication system and some datas has to be store in database.

If this is the case, you are not necessarily creating a Dapp (decentralized application) because you are required to have a centralized server.

A true decentralized application can operate without the login system or any authority over the smart contract.

In your scenario, you can use a users public address as their login information, as users have access to the private key associated with their public key.

Comment: The authentication system was just an example . My question was about storing data.

Comment: For decentralized authentication take a look at [uPort](https://www.uport.me) and [Blockstack](https://blockstack.org)